# Dependence of heat absorbed on different ways of heating

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Heat capacity depends on the delta Q (i.e small amount of heat absorbed) and delta T (i.e small change in temperature). My question is,why is the amount of heat absorbed different for different ways of heating up the system for the same amount of change in the temperature of the system ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you think this applies. If you define all the terms consistently it's not obvious that the heat absorbed IS different regardless of method. You may find the differences are in the way you describe or define what you are doing. How do you measure or define "temperature of the system" or "heat absorbed".

Answer (score 0):

Mechanism of heat transfer is different in different ways of heating up the system.

For example, in **Conduction**, heat is transferred by collision of neighbouring particles whereas in **Radiation** heat is transferred by means of electromagnetic radiation. Equations governing these two mechanisms are different. Therefore, heat transfer rate won't be same in both even if temperature gradient is same.

Answer (score 0):

As people have pointed out, the **total heat transferred** to raise or lower the temperature of an object by $\Delta T$ does not depend on how the object is heated. The **rate of temperature change** depends on the mode of heat transfer. For example, cooling by convection gives a **rate** proportional to $T$, while cooling by radiation gives a rate proportional to $T^4$. Cooling your object by conduction might be twice as fast as by convection, but the total heat transferred will be the same in both cases for the same $\Delta T$.

Comment: But isn't the mode of heat transfer depends upon the way of heating ? I mean, if one heats directly then it could be said that heat is transferred by conduction and on the other hand, if one does not heat it directly then it could be said that heat transfer has taken place by any other mode ?

Comment: Yes, the mode is the way of heating, kind of a semantic issue. But regardless of how you heat it, the same $\Delta T$ will be achieved with a given amount of heat in either scenario.